# how to draw an edge to the center of a node, but not quite?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following tikz code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node(A) [black, minimum size=2.2cm] {A} ;


\node(B) [black, minimum size=2.2cm, right=5cm of A] {B} ;


\draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}]
  (A) edge (B.center) ;

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I draw an edge to B.center, but I would like to have a relative repositioning of the end of the edge relative to B.center, meaning "draw an edge to the left of B.center by this and that, and above B.center by this and that"

Comment: `([yshift=1pt, xshift=2pt]B)` should draw the edge to 1pt above and 2pt to the right of B's center.

Comment: With the calc tikzlibrary you can use `($(b.center)+(1pt,2pt)$)`.

Comment: thank you, @JohnKormylo and Qrrbrbirlbel, that works.